# Multi-line Comment Boxes in Interactive PDFs with LaTeX

Tags: pdf, forms

I was looking to add a box to a pdf file in LaTeX.  I tried to use TextField, but that only allows an input on one line.  Is there a good command to make an box of more than one line and can be edited by clicking and typing in Adobe Reader?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the height of a text field and set the `multiline` option to *`true`*. Try this [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\noindent
\TextField[name=multilinetextbox, multiline=true, width=\linewidth,height=1in]{}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```